# Dont know how to use a drag and drop jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, drag-and-drop

I just find out this plugin http://www.konsolestudio.com/dad/, but i have no idea how to use it. I tried to follow the instructions, but they are not clear for me, and i cant't figure out how the plugin works. Can anyone give a hand? Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is the difference between this and jQuery's sortable ui?

Comment: The sortable ui in jQuery has tons of documentation and examples...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include sources

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-compat-git.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.konsolestudio.com/source/jquery.dad.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.konsolestudio.com/source/jquery.dad.css">
```

HTML

```
<div class="dad">
    <div>
        <div>1</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>2</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>3</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>4</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>5</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('.dad').dad();
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/atvty29u/1/**